# ImageView vector drawable causes the app crash on version 5.0.1

Tags: android, xml, vector

I am loading a vector drawable in xml for an ImageView. the app crashes only devices running API Version 21.

Here is the stack trace :

```
05-20 12:03:08.800 592-592/archub.lima.co.za.archub E/PathParser: error in parsing "c-2.5 0-4.71-1.28-6-3.22.03-1.99 4-3.08 6-3.08 1.99 0 5.97 1.09 6 3.08-1.29 1.94-3.5 3.22-6 3.22" 05-20 12:03:08.807 592-592/archub.lima.co.za.archub D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM 05-20 12:03:09.055 592-592/archub.lima.co.za.archub E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                  Process: archub.lima.co.za.archub, PID: 592
                                                                  android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #28: Error inflating class ImageView
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:916)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:802)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
at archub.lima.co.za.archub.FarmsFragment.onCreateView(FarmsFragment.java:220)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:742)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:570)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1177)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1025)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1545)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17448)
                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5465)
                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17448)
                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5465)
                                                                      at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:668)
                                                                      at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:735)
                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17448)
                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5465)
                                                                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
                                                                      at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17448)
                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5465)
                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17448)
                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5465)
                                                                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17448)
                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5465)
                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17448)                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5465)
                                                                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2560)
                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17448)
                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2031)
                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1189)
                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1402)
                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1077)
                                                                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable
```

Here's the `ImageView` which is creating the error. I find nothing wrong here. I've attached the full layout file below.

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_account_circle"
    android:contentDescription="@string/farm_icon" />
```

FarmFragment class- [FarmFragement.java](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/kgundula/4a7a6512c8a1e585a12c7c186513ac08/raw/609312e0a3482a8b1c1bc13fc9957b0902141118/FarmsFragment.java) and FarmFragment layout - [content_farms](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/kgundula/a7697e5741c805c103299014aecb0020/raw/91fda4c7ec4e8dfcd3615ef3a821da6c0007ba54/content_farms.xml)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the problem I had to use Android Studio to import the vector drawable instead of creating the vector drawable and add the SVG data.

"So the recommended way is to go through the SVG to XML conversion in Android Studio."

Here is the link to [issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=202670&can=1&q=vector%20drawable%205.0.1&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened)

Answer (score 0):

**trying to use app:srcCompat**

**

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    app:srcCompat ="@drawable/ic_account_circle"
    android:contentDescription="@string/farm_icon" />
```

**